# Imgur upload, get 403 error with message "invalid client_id" every few uploads

Tags: javascript, reactjs, imgur

For every 10 uploads, around 7 of them are successful and the rest get error "invalid_client_id"

The client_id is definitely correct because some cases are successful

[image]

[image]

Comment: Exactly the same issue here, only started noticing this in the last week tho...

Comment: given up, used firebase instead

Comment: same issue. was working fine last week. I'm guessing its a load problem on their side, idk.

Comment: Yeah my code was working fine for a couple of weeks then it started failing out of nowhere...

Answer (score 0):

Doesn’t appear that your Client ID is connected to an Imgur account. It may have been prior to this. Just go to Imgur’s api website and register your personal account or gaming account. Follow the instructions to get a new token. Then apply it to your script.